# Magento 2: Change Paypal Method Action for Some Products

Tags: magento2, custom, paypal, payment, magento-2.1.4

I have requirement that for X product. Payment will be Authorized & Capture later.
For other products it should be captured immediately.

So when user checkout with Paypal then i have to do this changes.

**magento\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Api\AbstractApi.php**

```
public function getPaymentAction()
{
    return $this->_getDataOrConfig('payment_action');
}
```

My only concern is which function should I override on basis of my condition?

Answer (score 1):

For paypal express **Magento/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php** class is responsible for process request and response.

Magento first call **callSetExpressCheckout**, it return token and this token is use for next nvp process.

Then check following:

Now go with following class
**Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php**

```
/**
 * Authorize or authorize and capture payment on gateway, if applicable
 * This method is supposed to be called only when order is placed
 *
 * @return $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 */
public function place()
{
.....
}
```

Check following line

```
$action = $methodInstance->getConfigPaymentAction();
```

[More Detail 1](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php#L334)

[More detail 2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Payment.php#L411)

Comment: Nope It already went to Paypal. Check for AJAX request `<path>/magento/paypal/express/gettoken/?button=0&_=1489052120354` Before it goes to Paypal we need to change that

Comment: For express check out Magento/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php class is responsible for request and response.

Comment: Magento/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php :: start

Comment: In Nvp.php public function call( ??

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: I hope this is the only method it calls First. Thanks @Sohel